# JSON serialization Error in Python 3.2

Tags: python, json

I am using JSON library and trying  to import a page feed to an CSV file. Tried many a ways to get the result however every time code execute it Gives JSON not serialzable. No Facebook use auth code which I have and used it so connection string will change however if you use a page which has public privacy you will still be able to get the result from below code.

following is the code

```
import urllib3
import json
import requests
#from pprint import pprint
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen

page_id = "abcd" # username or id
api_endpoint = "https://graph.facebook.com"
fb_graph_url = api_endpoint+"/"+page_id
try:
#api_request = urllib3.Requests(fb_graph_url)
    #http = urllib3.PoolManager()
    #api_response = http.request('GET', fb_graph_url)
    api_response = requests.get(fb_graph_url)
    try:
        #print (list.sort(json.loads(api_response.read())))
        obj = open('data', 'w')
        #    write(json_dat)
        f = api_response.content

        obj.write(json.dumps(f))
        obj.close()
    except Exception as ee:
        print(ee)
except Exception as e:
    print( e)
```

Tried many approach but not successful. hope some one can help

Comment: You are getting the webpage source not json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
requests.get(fb_graph_url).content
```

is probably a string. Using `json.dumps` on it won't work. This function expects a list or a dictionary as the argument.

If the request already returns JSON, just write it to the file.

Answer (score 1):

`api_response.content` is the text content of the API, not a Python object so you won't be able to dump it.

Try either:

```
f = api_response.content
obj.write(f)
```

Or

```
f = api_response.json()
obj.write(json.dumps(f))
```

Comment: Tried the Solutions provided however was getting must be str, not bytes and 'bytes' object has no attribute 'json' no resolution

Comment: Can you open an interactive session and print the content of `api_response.content`?